# Scanf() not working correctly in C when inputting value

Tags: c

I'm trying to work on a program to input a phone number and test if it is the right amount of digits in C, also checking if the first value is not 0 or 1. Scanf is not taking a value when I enter it and I do not understand why. If someone could please point out to me what the issue is it'd be much appreciated.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){

    int number = 0;
    int loop = 0;

    while(loop == 0){

        printf("Enter a phone number: ");
        scanf(" %d ", &number);
        printf("%d", number);
        
        int firstDigit;
        while(number >= 10){
                firstDigit = number/10;
            }

        if((number/1000000) >= 1 && (number/1000000) < 10){
            if(firstDigit == 1){
                printf("Invalid central office code: 1");
            }
            else if(firstDigit == 0){
                printf("Invalid central office code: 0");
            }
            else{
                int firstThree = (number/10000);
                int lastFour = (number%10000);
                printf("%d - %d", firstThree, lastFour);
            }
            
        }
        
        else if(number == 0){
            printf("Exiting.");
            loop = 1;
        }

        else{
            if((number/1000000)>=10){
             printf("Invalid phone number: too many digits");
            }
            else if((number/1000000)<1){
                printf("Invalid phone number: too few digits");
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reading input as a number will never have leading zeroes. You need to read it as a string.

Comment: Not sure but maybe the white spaces before and after the %d changes the format so you have to enter a space before the value.

Comment: You need to remove the extra spaces for scanf to read properly: `" %d "` -> `"%d"`

Comment: @Barmar I just discovered this issue after getting my code to be functional. I need to use int for the program as it's for school, is there an easy way to read leading zeros with scanf? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
while(number >= 10) {
    firstDigit = number/10;
}
```

is an infinite loop, because you are not modifying `number`.

What you probably want to do is:

```
while(number >= 10) {
    firstDigit = number/10;
    number /= 10;
}
```

---

You should avoid `scanf()` to read input. Better use `fgets()`, and then `sscanf()` for parsing.

```c
char input[1024]; // This should be large enough
if (!fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
    printf("Input error\n");
    return 1;
}

input[strcsnp(input, "\n")] = '\0'; // Because fgets reads \n so remove it

if (sscanf(input, "%d", &number) != 1) {
    printf("Parsing error\n");
    return 1;
}

// Use number...
```

Also, `scanf()` and `sscanf()` "ignore" the first `0`s you type as part of the phone number, so your solution might not be correct. The best way to represent a phone number is either by storing it as a string (as mentioned in a comment), or by defining a phone number structure.

Comment: This can be simplified.  If you're modifying the state of `number` in this way, there's no need to modify `firstDigit` each time. You can just `firstDigit = number;` after the loop, or directly use `number`.

Comment: @Zakk thanks for pointing out the loop issue I didn't realize at all. My program is functioning more as I planned but I need to use int for the phone number. Is there any way to get scanf to read the leading zeros? Thanks.

Comment: @Turk If you enter `00123456` as a phone number, `scanf("%d", &number)` will interpret it as if it was `123456`, and this is because `00123456` = `123456` numerically. So, if you want to read the starting `0`s, you have to parse your input as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Int size in c is 4 bytes, which can hold values only -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
It can't store all 10 digit values.

you can use long

```
long number = 0;
scanf("%ld", &number);
printf("%ld", number);
```

Comment: `scanf()` is a source of problems. It's better to avoid it.

Comment: `int` in C is not 4 bytes. C defines `int` so that `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT >= 16`. That means that `int` is only required to be at least 16 bits, but may also be 32 or 64 or 48 or whatever bits, as long as `int` is not wider than `long`. But yes, you're correct, `int` cannot be assumed to be wide enough to store 10-digit numbers.

Comment: @LucaPolito Practically, in almost all modern 32-bit and 64-bit machines, `int` size is 4 bytes.

Comment: @Zakk Correct, `int` is 4 bytes on most modern desktop/server platforms. But saying that `int` is 4 bytes in C is terribly wrong (also, 16-bits microcontrollers are not that rare, and C is especially used for low level programming, so it is not rare at all to encounter a 16-bit `int` in a C program).

Comment: `long` is also the wrong type to store a 10-digit number, because `long` is only required to be at least 32-bits, and *indeed* on Linux x64 `long` is 64-bit, but on Windows x64 `long` is 32-bit. The only correct data type for a phone number, by the way, is a string, not an integer (because integers "lose" the leading `0`s).